# Django: Lowercasing filename of the input Image File

Tags: django, django-admin, django-models

I have a model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    poster = models.ImageField(u"Poster", upload_to='img')
```

I'm using the admin to upload posters and save `Foo` objects. I now need to find a way to lowercase the filename before save. For instance POSTER.png or Poster.png or poster.PNG should be lowercased to poster.png.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`FileField.upload_to`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) may also be a callable, per this comment in the documentation:

> This may also be a callable, such as a function, which will be called to obtain the upload path, including the filename. This callable must be able to accept two arguments, and return a Unix-style path (with forward slashes) to be passed along to the storage system. The two arguments that will be passed are:

Since [`ImageField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) inherits all its attributes and methods from `FileField`, I think you could use:

```
def update_filename(instance, filename):
    path_you_want_to_upload_to = "img"
    return os.path.join(path_you_want_to_upload_to, filename.lower())

class Foo(models.Model):
    poster = models.ImageField(u"Poster", upload_to=update_filename)
```